# Tabbar Background color not display properly

Tags: ios, swift, tabbar

A color has same hexCode in Tabbar and header but it look different any solution ?

[Tabbbar Background color not display properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOK7Z.png)

Comment: doesnt look any different to me? just try disable translucent and see if it show correct color

Comment: there is no difference in color!! you can check it by `digital color meter` from your `mac` !!

Comment: @JaydeepModi You should check with some color pickers. They both have same hexCode. Acc to my color picker the hexCode is `fbbb2c`

Comment: yes it is right color code is same but why it look different? i also try translucent disable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to disable translucent property of Navigation controller .

[image]